# Android connecting to Java Server

Tags: java, android, servlets, server, webserver

I'm new in android studio I'd like to know how can I make requests to a server.
I wanted that in my Android App I sign up an account and my server stores all the users, something simple just to start. The next step that i want is like passing some strings or objects to other users.

How can I do that? 
Is recommended to do my Server in Java/Python?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

I would suggest you first google your queries, since there are many such repositories on GitHub.

First Link when I searched Android CRUD was this
https://github.com/budasuyasa/simple-android-crud

As for Java or Python, all depends on your skill set, what I would recommend is using Spring boot for backend services but you can also use Flask to create Rest services in Python.

Have fun coding

Comment: I know the example here is using expressJS but you will get gist of what to do next